# How to make round border with gap in swatch in css?

Tags: css, magento2.4, swatches

I have to make orange border of swatches like below image

[image]

I made round swatches in magneto 2.4 and it look like below image

[image]

My css code

```
.swatch-option{border-radius:50%;min-width: 18px;width: 18px !important;height: 18px !important;border: none;}
```

Here above image there is a square outline in magento. But I want round outline like first image. How could I achieve this ?

Comment: It might be useful if you could paste the current HTML/CSS markup of the swatches so that people have quicker access to the being able to modify the CSS without needing to setup swatches on a blank Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Try below css for selected option

```
.swatch-option.selected{border: 2px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 50%; box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 2pt #ff5501;}
```

[image]

and for hover options

```
.swatch-option.image:not(.disabled):hover, .swatch-option.color:not(.disabled):hover{outline: none; border: 2px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 50%; box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 2pt #ff5501;}
```

Thanks!

Comment: thank you for your code,but your code make smaller selected solid circle,but I want to make outline circle without making small solid cricle.

Comment: What do you mean by small solid circle. Can't get you.

Comment: when you make red border and when you increase white border border: 1px solid #ffffff; it makes whilte border gap inside rather than outside so then selected round color makes smaller,but I want make outside white border of selected color

Comment: @NirajPatel outside red border is achieved using **box-shadow**. So you can increase outer red border using this `box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 3pt #ff5501;` when you increase inside white border. Let me know if it works for you. Thanks!

Comment: you understood wrong. Right now white border put inside, but I want make white border outside.

Comment: when you increase white border circle will be become small because border increase inside, but I want white border outside

Comment: In that case just change the box shadow color to white. You can not put space between solid circle and it's border. You need to use box shadow for this.